# Add <li> in specific place

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to achieve the following: I want to enable the user to add sections above or beyond, each section can expand, and inside every section the user will be able to add files above or beyond. as showen in picture:

[image]

For example if user wants to add section above it will look like:

[image]

For now my code always add the section to the end, here my code:

```js
function addSection() {
  $("#header ul").append(
    '<li ><button onclick="addSection()">Add Section</button></li><li><button type="button" class="collapsible">Open Section 1</button><div class="content"><button>upload file</button></div></li></li><li><button  onclick="addSection()">Add Section</button></li>'
  );
  handleEvents();
}


function handleEvents() {
  var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].removeEventListener("click", function() {});
  }

  for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var content = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (content.style.display !== "none") {
        content.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        content.style.display = "block";
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #90ee90;
}

body {
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="header">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li>
      <button onclick="addSection()">Add Section</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button type="button" class="collapsible">Open Section 1</button>
      <div class="content">
        <button>upload file</button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button onclick="addSection()">Add Section</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things we need to improve first before we can do this with the current code.

- You need to somehow know what type of `addSection` button you are pressing and what is the intention. Is it a button that wants to create a section above or a button that wants to create a section below. On how to convey this you can do the following.

  - You can decide to add data attributes to your buttons and then read that data attribute when the click event happens
  - You can decide to pass a parameter to your function `addSection` that will tell you intention of the click
- You can to use jQuery utility to `append` or `prepend` to sibling sections. To find the sibling section you can use jQuery `.closest`. Using this utility you can discover the closest sibling to your click.

With this in mind we can build the following code:

```
function addSection(dir) {
    // we are now passing a dir as in direction
    // to know if we should append or prepend

    // lets get the total count of sections 
    var sectionsCount = $('.collapsible').length;

    // create next section
    var item = getListItem(sectionsCount);

    // find what is the closes section where the click originated
    var closestLi = $(this.event.target).closest('li');

    // check the dir
    if(dir === 'up') {
      $(closestLi).prepend(item);
    }
    if(dir === 'down') {
      $(closestLi).append(item);
    }
    handleEvents();
}
```

You can find a full working demo here if you wanna fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ft1xou2v/2/

```js
function getListItem(sectionsCount) {
   return '<li ><button onclick="addSection(\'up\')">Add Section ↑</button></li><li><button type="button" class="collapsible">Open Section '+ sectionsCount +'</button><div class="content"><button>upload file</button></div></li></li><li><button onclick="addSection(\'down\')">Add Section ↓</button></li>';
  }
 function addSection(dir) {
  var sectionsCount = $('.collapsible').length;
  var item = getListItem(sectionsCount);
  var closestLi = $(this.event.target).closest('li');
 if(dir === 'up') {
    $(closestLi).prepend(item);
  }
  if(dir === 'down') {
    $(closestLi).append(item);
  }
  handleEvents();
}


function handleEvents() {
  var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].removeEventListener("click", function() {});
  }

  for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
    coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var content = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (content.style.display !== "none") {
        content.style.display = "none";
      } else {
        content.style.display = "block";
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #90ee90;
}

body {
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li>
      <button onclick="addSection('up')">Add Section ↑</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button type="button" class="collapsible">Open Section 0</button>
      <div class="content">
        <button>upload file</button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button onclick="addSection('down')">Add Section ↓</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```